# Dynamically created routes only work if app is re-initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

In my web application "subsites" and pages are created on the fly. Routes are added the `RouteTable.Routes` whenever a new subsite is created, or (sometimes) when a new page is created. Something like this:

```
public static Site RegisterSite(Site site) {
    DeregisterSite(site);

    // Register non-auto-routed pages first so the default route doesn't override them.
    foreach (SitePage page in site.SitePages.Where(o => !o.IsAutoRouted))
        RegisterPageRoute(site, page);

    RegisterDefaultRoute(site);

    return site;
}

// Both RegisterPageRoute and RegisterDefaultRoute eventually make it here...
private static Route RegisterRoute(int siteId, string routeName, Route route) {
    using (RouteTable.Routes.GetWriteLock()) {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(routeName, route);
    }

    return route;
}
```

I've debugged the creation of a new site and when the site is created, the route is registered correctly (`RouteTable.Routes` includes the new routes). If I then attempt to browse to the URL(s) which would be served by the new route(s), they never make it to the controller which is supposed to serve them -- I get a hard IIS error page:

> The resource cannot be found.

So, if the routes are being added, why aren't they being "seen" when the MVC framework receives a request for one of the new routes? Am I missing a step somewhere? Do I need to tell the MVC framework to "reload" the route table?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, routes were being added in this order:

1. Site-based routes (very specific)
2. Root home page (not specific)

So routing worked correctly, *on first load*, but new routes were being added to the end of the route table, after the non-specific "other routes". So, that non-specific route was picking up all requests once it was hit.

The solution is simple, either:

1. Don't create non-specific routes, or
2. Rebuild the entire route table in the proper order when new sites/pages are added, or
3. Make sure new site/page routes are added to the top of the route table: `RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, newRoute)`